# Is there any helper function that assign form data into model in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I know that there is a `resource` functionality in laravel and as far as I know `resource` is something like `json` to `model` and its reverse..

So when I process form data, currently, use following custom helper method..

```
public function assignFormdata(Request $request, $model, $map = [])
{
    foreach($map as $input=>$field) {
        // $field is model's param. $input is form data key.
        $model->$field = $request->input($input) ?? $field;
    }
    return $model;
}
```

.. Is this method already exist in laravel? or something similar..?

Comment: Can you rephrase the problem, and also add with what you need the help?, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "standard" way in Laravel, that I am aware of, that will accomplish what you have above, where you assign a default value to an input if it is missing, and control what attributes are being set using the `map`.

The closest thing to what you are looking for is [Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment), I believe.

There are many different methods and patterns to handle these types of requests, and your approach seems fine to me. I personally use [Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#form-request-validation) + [DTO](https://github.com/spatie/data-transfer-object) because the code documents itself quite well. As an example:

Controller:

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    ...

    public function store(CreateUserRequest $request)
    {
        $user = User::create($request->toCommand());

        // Return response however you like
    }

    ...
}
```

FormRequest

```
class CreateUserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    ...

    public function rules()
    {
        // Validate all the data here
    }

    ...

    public function toCommand() : CreateUserCommand
    {
        return new CreateUserCommand([
            'name' => $this->input('name'),
            'birthdate' => Carbon::parse($this->input('birthdate')),
            'role' => $this->input('role'),
            'gender' => $this->input('gender'),
            ...
        ]);
    }
}
```

Command DTO

```
class CreateUserCommand extends DataTransferObject
{
    /** @var string */
    public $name;

    /** @var \Carbon\Carbon */
    public $birthdate;

    /** @var string */
    public $role = 'employee'; // Sets default to employee

    /** @var null|string */
    public $gender;            // Not required  
}
```

```
class User extends Model
{
    ...

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'birthdate',
        'role',
        'gender',
    ]; 

    ...


    public static function create(CreateUserCommand $command)
    {
        // Whatever logic you need to create a user
        return parent::create($command->toArray());
    }
}
```

That is a fairly "Laravel way" of doing things, and the code itself conveys a lot of information to anyone else (and you later :D) who needs to use it.